# how to declare SQLCA.SQLERRD?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to insert records into a table using insert....select...stmt in a oracle stored procedure. How do find  the number of records inserted using SQLERRD?

```
recIn number;
Insert into t1 ....Select.....;
recIn := SQLCA.SQLERRD(3);
....
....
PLS-00201: identifier 'SQLCA.SQLERRD' must be declared
```

is the error message thrown. How do you declare SQLCA.SQLERRD?

```
using Oracle 9.2

bcs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using PL/SQL?  Or are you using Pro*C/C++?  `SQLCA.SQLERRD` would be defined in Pro*C/C++, it would not be defined in PL/SQL.  Since you didn't tag the question for Pro*C, I'm guessing that you're just using PL/SQL.

In PL/SQL, you simply reference `SQL%ROWCOUNT` after running a SQL statement to get the row count.  Something like

```
DECLARE
  l_num_rows INTEGER;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO t1( <<list of columns>> )
    SELECT <<list of columns>>
      FROM <<some tables>>
     WHERE <<some predicates>>
  l_num_rows := sql%rowcount;
  dbms_output.put_line( 'The statement inserted ' || l_num_rows || ' rows.';
END;
```

Comment: Thank you Justin. Did'nt know it was to be used with Pro*C/C++. Am using PL/SQL.